# What is the most straightforward way to convert a list of numpy arrays into a single numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

[image]

What is the most straightforward way to convert the list to the numpy array as shown?

I tried to to `numpy.asarray()` but it resulted in a 3 axis, with the data in the resulting array being transposed, although the values are combined.

UPDATED:

So `asarray().reshape(1,3)` works with single row. But the element in my list is of size (2,1) or greater, it seems the reshape does not transpose properly. How can i do it?

[image]

Updated:

Managed to do it with 2 steps: `reshape(3,2)` then `np.transpose()`. I wonder if there is a single step approach?

Comment: Forgot to say - please post code, not images.

Answer (score 1):

You are lists all have two dimensions. It seems you are looking to [flatten](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html) that:

```
>>> x=[[1]]
>>> y=[[2]]
>>> z=[[3]]
>>> np.array((x,y,z)).flatten()
array([1, 2, 3])
```

If you want 3 columns and one row, you can reshape specifically:

```
>>> np.array((x,y,z)).reshape(1,3)
array([[1, 2, 3]])
```

Note this is two dimensional. The flat array is one dimensional, so there is no sense of row and column to it - you can `reshape(3,1)` to see the difference to a 3x1 array.

To answer your edit, I do not think any other way would be much more elegant than

```
>>> x=[[1],[2]]
>>> y=[[3],[4]]
>>> z=[[5],[6]]
>>> np.array((x,y,z)).reshape(3,2).T
array([[1, 3, 5],
       [2, 4, 6]])
```

and it is quite optimal as well. Using `.T` will save you an explicit call to `np.transpose`.

Comment: thanks for the reply. it results in a 3 rows x 1 col array. how can i tranpose it? i ran transpose() but it ended up with the same result

Comment: @Corse I missed that - that is considered multi-dimensional (shape (1,3), so you have two dimensions). See edit.

Comment: @Corse also note that is not entirely correct. There is a difference between shape `(3,)` and shape `(3,1)` - try the two reshapes to see what 3 rows x 1 col really looks like.

Comment: what does (3,) mean? empty column?

Comment: @Corse it means a one dimensional entity, with no meaning to row and column. I will take a look at the update, but please be advised it is quite impolite to change questions after getting an answer - next time ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a 2-D (line or column) array, you can use `np.atleast_2d` with `np.flatten` as answered above:

```
x = np.arange(10).reshape((2,5))
print(x)
>>array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
   [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])

x_new = np.atleast_2d(x.flatten())
print(x_new) 
>> array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])

x_new = np.atleast_2d(x.flatten()).T
print(x_new) 
>> array([[0],
   [1],
   [2],
   [3],
   [4],
   [5],
   [6],
   [7],
   [8],
   [9]])
```

Answer (score 0):

- Case A: combine a list of three arrays with shape `(1, 1)` into an array of shape `(1, 3)`
- Case B: combine a list of three arrays with shape `(2, 1)` into an array of shape `(2, 3)`

Constraint: do it in a single step. (Presumably, a single "step" is a single function call.)

General answer: concatenate them! The function [`numpy.concatenate()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) takes a list of arrays and sticks them together along an arbitrary axis. The only constraint is that the shape of the arrays must be the same along all other dimensions.

The following example shows how to combine a list of `N` arrays with shape `(K, 1)` into an array of shape `(K, N)`.

```
import numpy as np

list_of_arrays = [np.array([[1], [2]]), np.array([[10], [20]]), np.array([[100], [200]])]

assert list_of_arrays[0].shape == (2, 1)
assert list_of_arrays[1].shape == (2, 1)
assert list_of_arrays[2].shape == (2, 1)

result = np.concatenate(list_of_arrays, axis=1)  # single step: list -> array

assert result.shape == (2, 3)
```